# How can I use yarn api to add node_modules in distribution package?

Tags: node.js, gulp, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I want to run `yarn install` programmatically in `gulpfile.js` to add node_modules in a distribution package.
Currently, I am just spawning a command `yarn install --production`.
However, I am wondering if I can call yarn programmatically because it might improve performance and I can customize the installation.

Below is my current working code

```
const installModules = async () => {
  await copyFile(
    path.join(__dirname, 'package.json'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'cli', 'package.json')
  )
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cp = spawn('yarn', ['install', '--production'], {
      shell: true,
      cwd: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'cli'),
    })

    cp.on('spawn', () => {
      console.log(`promisifiedSpawn child process spawn`)
    })
    cp.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(`promisifiedSpawn child process error: ${error}`)
      reject(error)
    })
    cp.on('close', (code, signal) => {
      console.log(`promisifiedSpawn child process closed with code: ${code}`)
      console.log(`signal: ${signal}`)
      resolve()
    })

    cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
    cp.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
  })
  await unlink(path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'cli', 'package.json'))
}
```